# How to get the incoming email address -Sharepoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I want to send the email to the sharepoint adminsitrator when user clicks the form button. How I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution for this scenario is to create a workflow with [SharePoint Designer 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/default.aspx). Here is an article that describes how to create a [workflow that sends an email](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA102390421033.aspx). You can manually choose administrators you want to mail, but it is much better approach to create a SharePoint group for admins and send an email to this group.

Make sure you have properly configured [SharePoint outgoing email settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263462.aspx).

Comment: I have a user control where I have created form...and on click of a button I want to send the email....so I wonder I can't use sharepoint designer method....

Answer (score 0):

Upvoted Toni's but since the OP tagged it as C#, the function to send emails using the Central Administration is called [SPUtiliy.SendEmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.sendemail.aspx). To grab the email of the user (if you dont know the email) you could go with something like `SPContext.Current.Web.AllUsers["DOMAIN\login"].Email` (not test environment here, syntax may be off)

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use SPutility I m using .net mail option for it.....any idea how to get without SPutility...

Comment: Then you need to extract the user email the same way I described above, and send the email normally like on: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072606-1.aspx